# bin/magento setup:upgrade not running magento 2.3.X

Tags: php, xml, xsd, magento2

I have installed magento 2.3.x on my localhost. There were few extension requirements that were not achieved during the installation but I was able to fix those. Overall, my frontend and backend is now running well on localhost.

However, I wanted to add a field in customer form
[customer form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I9Fg.png)

but, I am not able to run the `setup:update` command. I have tried these

```
"php bin/magento setup:upgrade"
```

and

```
"runas php bin/magento setup:upgrade"
```

but the command is not working. Here is the screenshot
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QAhp.png)

I am using Windows and XAMPP (php 7.2), Magento 2.3.X.
Any help is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/magento-2-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-on-windows

Comment: It would be good to have the error message as text in the question, instead of trapped in that screenshot. Could you paste it in? Thanks, and welcome.

Comment: @MartinBurch, Sorry, I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @CodeSpirit, Thanks for the thread, that solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
php bin/magento list
```

When everything is working correctly, this should list out all of the possible commands in your Magento 2 command line interface.

If there is an error, you will see a detailed description in CMD